# Laravel localization to German and special letters

Tags: laravel, character-encoding, localization, laravel-blade

I have a problem with some German's special letters (ö, ü...) in my Laravel application.

My encoding is set to UTF-8.

Everything works fine with the content from the database (where is `utf8_general_ci`). When I hardcode some text to Blade view files, that's fine, too. But, I'm using localization files (`/app/lang/de/myFile.php`) with an associative array.

German characters from that array are displayed as � � �. What is strange, when I `var_dump(trans('myFile.key'))` in Blade, special characters works, but when `echo trans('myFile.key')`, there are that question marks.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after few hours :) I succeed! The point is to save localization file in UTF-8 encoding. Sublime Text by default saved it as Windows-1250.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem with one of my projects; not sure if it is related though. Different web browsers handle locale and translations differently. Once in Firefox `&pound;` did not work properly unless you changed the browser's locale to UK. However, `&163;` worked universally. Opera seemed to work across the board but IE and Firefox had strange behavior when trying to use characters or symbols not native to the locale the browser was in.

First thing I would attempt is to [change your browser's language](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Browser%27s-Language) and see if that fixes it. If so then the issue will be on how the browser is interpreting what gets returned. If this fixes it then there is a strong chance this will not be an issue for German speakers because their browser will (should) already support the language.

If not, then the problem could lay in the formatting of the files on the server. If the files are being stored on the webserver as ANSI then that could supersede the output. We had this problem as well due to an NFS mount and some windows users/editors. The most failsafe method I could suggest is changing ö and ü to `&246;` and `&252;` but I can understand where this would get tedious.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, looks like this problem is more complex then I thought. Just to say, if I change encoding manually in my web browser settings, and set to Windows-1250 or Windows-1252, question marks are gone and everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, localization has not been a fun task and has caused a lot of unseen results. I wish you better luck than we have encountered.